# Find the smallest/largest scalar that converts a vector of reals to a vector of integers

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, integers, signal-processing, estimation, floating-point

Suppose there are two vectors: $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{Z}^N_+$. If I know that $\mathbf{x} = \alpha \cdot \mathbf{y}$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, is there a way to estimate $\alpha$ given only $\mathbf{x}$? Put another way, if I know that a vector of floats was created by multiplying a vector of positive integers by a floating point scalar, can I estimate that scalar accurately?

Edit:

The problem can be framed another way: Given a vector of real numbers, find the (smallest/largest) scalar that converts them all to integers.

Comment: Do you have access to the value of $y$?

Comment: @Youem No. Only $\mathbf{x}$ and the fact that $\mathbf{y}$ is composed solely of integers.

Comment: Do you have reason to think that there is such a scalar?

Comment: @Lubin Yes. It is stipulated to be the case, at least to double-precision.

Comment: Choose a non-zero entry $x_0$ of $\mathbf x$ and form $\mathbf x/x_0$. All entries of this vector are rational; find the smallest positive integer $m$ that makes $m(\mathbf x/x_0)$ have integer entries. Then take $\alpha = m/x_0$. We could also factor out the GCD of the entries of $m(\mathbf x/x_0)$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff But how do you find $m$?

Comment: If the LCM of the denominators in $\mathbf y$ is know to be small, then you could just iterate and test all positive integers. Other than that, I don't know.